# Seperate .com domain name purchasing for a VPS

Tags: web-hosting, domains, domain-registration

I am looking at getting a VPS with RackSRV, and they don't sell domain names, but are happy to set it up after I get one elsewhere.

Can anyone recommend somewhere I can purchase just the domain, and not have any hassles moving it afterwards?

(Or can I just purchase the domain and make it point at the RackSRV ip address, while still using the domain sellers' control panel? I don't really understand that part of it enough! :))

I want the domain name registered in my name, ideally with myself as the technical and administrative contacts for simple transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are thousands of companies out there that sell domain names. Two of the most popular (IMHO) are GoDaddy (shudder) and Network Solutions (also, shudder). Ignoring my shivers, GoDaddy has some decent prices (and questionable practices and horrible control panel) and Network Solutions was featured in the "Social Network."

Personally, I'd reccomend someone like [1&1](http://1and1.com). They have decent prices for domains and are somewhat friendly. Also, their control panel is pretty decent and easy to use when you need to access it.

In your situation, you wouldn't want to move the domain, you'd just want to point the domain to your server through the registrar's control panel.

Comment: I like godaddy for domain registrations. My only real complaint with them is the heavy upsell you have to deal with when making your purchase.

Comment: Again, GoDaddy is great for registering domains, from a price perspective, but I really think that their control panel is lacking and confusing and they have a bad reputation with some of the things that they have done.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've used 1and1 before for hosting but I want the power of a VPS for my future websites. I don't suppose you also know how I would go about pointing the domain through the 1and1 control panel, or perhaps a link to the information?

Comment: http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domain_admin/dns_settings/13.html

Comment: 123-reg.co.uk have decent prices and an awesome control panel! Very slick!

Comment: also, iwantmyname.com is fairly decent. full dns control and easy one-click setups with other third party services (like outlook.com, gmail, etc.)...

Comment: GoDaddy recently updated their domain control panel so it's easier to use. They have friendly, highly professional support reachable 24/7 by phone - not so common. I'd suggest to anyone thinking about using 1&1 to first Google "1&1 complaints". They have horrendous billing and custom service practices, but otherwise decent service.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase your domain from any ICANN accredited registrar.
To get a list of all the ICANN accredited registrars, use this link: http://www.icann.org/registrar-reports/accredited-list.html

Use the DNS manager and set 'A' record '@' and your IP.